# Changing Folder Permissions in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, icacls

I have a vbscript that will create a folder, but I need the User to have Full Permissions.  I have put my code below. (Windows 8 system)

```
FSO.CreateFolder(lclFolder)
oWS.exec "icacls " & lclFolder & " /reset /inheritance:r /grant:r Users:(OI)(CI)F /T"
```

I have the script running as Administrator using:

```
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
    , WScript.ScriptFullName & " /elevate", "", "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
End If
```

The folder gets created, but the User permissions were: read & execute, List folders contents & Read. After the icacls line was inserted, this did not change.  Can anyone advise where I went wrong?

Comment: so elevate the vbscript with a user's that has full permission with [`runas`.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx)  What you are trying to do is a privilaged task.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The script should be running as Administrator (I've put some code above).  I'm still new to vb, so might be missing something basic/obvious - sorry.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  If you have elevated the permisions of the process running the vbscript then it should execute without a problem.  It should work exactly like if you had run the command itself in an elevated command prompt in fact.

Comment: The folder gets created, but the User permission were: read & execute, List folders contents & Read.  I was wanting to change the permissions to Full control.  I thought my syntax may be off for the icalcs line because the  folder still only has the basic permissions for the User - not full.

Comment: I strongly suggest you update your question to include an actual question.  You have provided the required explaination of what you want, now, just include that in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Exec Method (Windows Script Host)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/ateytk4a(v=vs.84).aspx):

> The command line should appear exactly as it would if you typed it at
>   the command prompt.

Therefore, force embedding folder name in a pair of `"` double quotes as follows:

```
oWS.exec "icacls """ & lclFolder & """ /reset /inheritance:r /grant:r Users:(OI)(CI)F /T"
```

or as follows:

```
oWS.exec "icacls " & CHR(34) & lclFolder & CHR(34) & " /reset /inheritance:r /grant:r Users:(OI)(CI)F /T"
```

Comment: Thanks very much for both your replies.  It looks like it was the missing inverted commas that was scuppering me.  I also ended up just using /grant User...  It seems the (OI)(CI) reference is important to include though, so at least I got that right.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [TAKEOWN](http://ss64.com/nt/takeown.html) command.

Try using the example seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333972/set-permissions-with-a-vbs-script). Maybe it's me but the example code makes more sense than the `.vbs` you provided.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strFile = "c:\test_folder\test_file.txt"
setPerms = "%COMSPEC% /c echo Y| C:\windows\system32\cacls.exe " & Chr(34) & strFile & Chr(34) & " /G domain\everyone:F"
wscript.echo setPerms
WshShell.run setPerms
```

Change the `strFile` directory and `domain\everyone` to your preference.

Furthermore I'm inclined to think that the Cacls command isn't being executed with admin privileges through and through. This is the `.VBS` script I use to elevate commands, files, scripts, etc... and it involves **encasing** the command you want executed as Admin. Bare in mind it also executes silently but you can take that option out.

```
bElevate = False
if WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then If WScript.Arguments(WScript.Arguments.Count-1) <> "|" then bElevate = True
if bElevate Or WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then ElevateUAC
REM run the following script with admin privilages. start point.
```

RUN THIS COMMAND AS ADMIN

```
REM the above script will be run with admin privilages. end point.
Sub ElevateUAC
    sParms = " |"
    If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then
            For i = WScript.Arguments.Count-1 To 0 Step -1
            sParms = " " & WScript.Arguments(i) & sParms
        Next
    End If
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    oShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", WScript.ScriptFullName & sParms, , "runas", 1
    WScript.Quit
End Sub
```